# Google sign in in Android Things is very very slow

Tags: google-signin, android-things

I'm developing an app for Android Things running on a Raspberry Pi3, currently using the developer preview 8, but this problem happened in the previous versions of Android Things too.

I tested it with different firebase/play services version, from 11.4.2 until version 15.0.0, without difference.

I'm implementing a google sign in as explained here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

The whole process works, but it works very very slow. It takes a lot of time (20 o 30 seconds, sometimes more), until each screen for the login process is showed. For example, it takes more than 20 seconds until the first screen where the user introduces the email address is showed. After that the user does click the next button, and it takes again a lot of time until the screen for the password is showed.

After introducing the password, and waiting for the policy privacy agreement screen, and finally pressing I agree, it can take a couple of minutes until the control is returned to the activity that started the process. Sometimes the result intent is returned, sometimes not...

Actually, the sign in process is not usable. The users will not be so patient.

After the Google Sign In, the process to exchange the credentials with Firebase and "login in" into firebase is very fast, the problem happens only on the "google sign in" part.

I tested the FirebaseUI Auth library, with the same results.

Is somebody else experimenting this problem by Android Things?

Regards!

Comment: have you ran your code on an Android Emulator to confirm it is an Android Things problem?

Comment: Yes, of course. The same code works smooth if I use it in other app that runs in a normal Android device or emulator.